# Unable to run sever due to npm not navigating to the incorrect directory. and find the package.jason

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, package.json

I have used `vue create` to make a project. This worked with no problem. Then when attempting to run `npm run serve` I ran into the issue of node not being able to find the `package.json` file that was created when vue created the project.

I ran into the same problem when trying to learn webpack before moving on to vue cli. I was unable to figure that out either. But means that this is not original to vue.

I am going to attempt to reinstall node to see if that fixes it but I don't believe that it will.

In addition, I want to comment that it seems as though npm is always looking in the wrong location. Or expecting the file in the wrong place

I am running:

- Windows 10 version 2004 os build 19041.1052
- node version 14.17.0

**Error**:

> ```
> 0 info it worked if it ends with ok
> 1 verbose cli [
>
> 1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
>
> 1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
> 1 verbose cli   'run',
>
> 1 verbose cli   'serve'
>
> 1 verbose cli ]
>
> 2 info using npm@6.14.13
>
> 3 info using node@v14.17.0
>
> 4 verbose stack Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\VueProjects\package.
>
> 5 verbose cwd C:\VueProjects
>
> 6 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19041
>
> 7 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program 
> Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "serve"
>
> 8 verbose node v14.17.0
>
> 9 verbose npm  v6.14.13
>
> 10 error code ENOENT
>
> 11 error syscall open
>
> 12 error path C:\VueProjects\package.json
>
> 13 error errno -4058
>
> 14 error enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 
> 'C:\VueProjects\package.json'
>
> 15 error enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
>
> 16 verbose exit [ -4058, true ]
> ```

[image: Error Code]

[image]

ps. Ill be watching this as much as I can wile trying to fix it as well

Comment: Please include all text information as text, not as a picture of text.

Comment: Line 42 in your first screenshot appears to be returning incorrect path with a forward slash instead of a backslash. Maybe start there.

Comment: I have added the whole error report. Mers i cannot find ware that path is located

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your second screenshot your project files are not located directly in `C:\Vue Projects\`, that is why it can't find your `package.json`. When you run `npm run <some-script-name>` you need to be in your project's root directory, which in your case is `C:\Vue Projects\componets`.

Comment: I have adde3d a second photo. In which it should show that I the file there already. I addition I want to comment that is seem as though npm is always looking in the wrong location. Or expecting the file in the wrong place

Comment: @CharlesEvans Based on your second screenshot it appears that all of the files are within the dir titled `componets`. Check File Explorer, or list the contents of the dir in Powershell/Command Prompt to confirm. Then please mark my answer as correct.

Comment: @CharlesEvans In VS Code if you toggle the caret icon next `componets` do all of your source files collapse into it?

Comment: the project that I am working on is called components which does have a package. json file. vue projects is a directory  holding the components project

Comment: and yes everything collapses into it

Comment: @CharlesEvans You have to run your `npm run serve` from within that folder then. Based on the error report it appears you are running it from `C:\Vue Projects` because it's looking for `C:\Vue Projects\package.json`. In your terminal you need to run `cd C:\Vue Projects\componets` then `npm run serve`

Comment: In reference to your title, npm will not "navigate" to the correct directory to find your `package.json`. When you do `npm run serve` or any other script defined in your project it expects there to be a `package.json` in the same dir that you are running the command from.